# Sum of elements of two integer array in a single string array in Java

Tags: java, java-8

i have a a string array which contains two integer array  ["[1,2,3]","[4,5,6,7,8]"]

I want to add the elements of integer array for example - 1+4,2+5,3+6 and store and print the result in a single integer array -  [4,7,9,7,8]

What is the efficient approach to solving this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: 1) Create a new array `c` with length of the bigger array `b`. 2) iterate from `i=0` to the length of the smaller array `a`. 3) add the numbers at index `i` of both arrays (`a`, `b`) and put them into the new array `c` at index `i`. 4) put the remaining elements of the bigger array `b` into the new array `c`

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strArray={"[1,2,3]","[4,5,6,7,8]"};
String[] s1=strArray[0].substring(1, strArray[0].length() - 1).split(",");
String[] s2=strArray[1].substring(1, strArray[1].length() - 1).split(",");

// put string array length which ever length is bigger like in this case s2 is bigger than s1 and loop through it.
Integer[] output = new Integer[s2.length];

for(int i=0; i < s2.length; i++) {
    if(i < s1.length) {
        output[i] = Integer.parseInt(s1[i]) + Integer.parseInt(s2[i]);
    } else {
        output[i] = Integer.parseInt(s2[i]);
    }
}
            
for(int j=0;j<output.length;j++) {
    System.out.println(output[j]);
}
```

Comment: This will fail for e.g: `{"[4,5,6,7,8]", "[1,2,3]"}`

Comment: this is logic for input given in question you can check which string array length is greater and loop according to it. for e.g. in your input case first string array length is greater you can put s2 =strArray[0].substring(1, strArray[0].length()-1).split(",");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] strArray={"[1,2,3]","[4,5,6,7,8]"};

String[] strArray1 = strArray[0].substring(1, strArray[0].length()-1).split(",");
String[] strArray2 = strArray[1].substring(1, strArray[1].length()-1).split(",");

int maxArrLength = Math.max(strArray1.length, strArray2.length);

int[] resultIntArray = new int[maxArrLength];

for (int i=0; i < maxArrLength; i++) {
    if (strArray1.length>i) resultIntArray[i] += Integer.valueOf(strArray1[i]);
    if (strArray2.length>i) resultIntArray[i] += Integer.valueOf(strArray2[i]);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultIntArray));
```